# Необходимо извлечь значения до двоеточия и после в списке: ['100: 2', ' 423519061: 1', ' 256079106: 1']

Tags: python, python-3.x

Дано:

```
 list = ['100: 2', ' 423519061: 1', ' 256079106: 1']
```

Результат:

```
index = [100, 423519061, 256079106]
number = [2, 1, 1]
```

Я думал сделать как-то вот так:

```
for a in result_users_sub:
        a = result_users_sub #все до двоеточия
        # INSERT INTO DB
        a = result_users_sub #все после двоеточия
        # INSERT INTO DB
```

Comment: как бы вы извлекли значения, если бы только одна строка была, а не список строк? У вас есть сложности, с тем, чтобы элемент из списка достать? Или выполнить действия над каждым элементом в списке?

Comment: @Scarabyte содержательно полезное замечание, но форму можно было бы более вежливую выбрать. [Как избежать буквальных ответов на очевидно неграмотные вопросы?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4144/23044)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
l = ['100: 2', ' 423519061: 1', ' 256079106: 1']
s = [s.split(':') for s in l]
before, after = zip(*s)
before = list(map(int, before))
after = list(map(int, after))
```

Результат:

```
>>> before
[100, 423519061, 256079106]
>>> after
[2, 1, 1]
```

Comment: `index, number = zip(*[map(int, s.split(':')) for s in ['100: 2', ' 423519061: 1', ' 256079106: 1']])`